# wp_mail returns true but not receiving mails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, email

I am using wp_mail() to receive mails which is submitted through a contact form in my wordpress blog. wp_mail() returns true but the thing is i am not receiving any mails. I have also tried to change the mail address to hotmail from gmail but no luck.

**Ajax code in my contact template**

```
$('#send').click(function() {
    //For Validation
    function validateText(name) {
        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z'-.\s]+$/;
        if (pattern.test(name)) {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
    //For Validation
    function validateMail(mail) {
        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        //var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
        if (pattern.test(mail)) {
            return true;
        }     
        return false;
    }
    //Getting values from the form
    var name = $('#name').val(), mail = $('#mailid').val(), query = $('#message').val(), error = 1;
    //For Validation
    if(name == "" || !(validateText(name))) {
        $('#name').addClass('error');
        error = 0;
    }
    ////For Validation
    if(mail == "" || !(validateMail(mail))) {
        $('#mailid').addClass('error');
        error = 0;
    }
    //For Validation
    if(query == "") {
        $('#message').addClass('error');
        error = 0; 
    }
    if(!error) { // If validation fails
        return false;
    }

    $('#sendAlert').show();
        $('#send').html('Sending...');
        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, { // Using ajax post method to send data
            action: 'ajax_action',
            sendmail: 'nothing',
            name: name,
            mail: mail,
            query: query
        }, function(data) {
            $('#send').html('Send');
            alert(data); // Alerting response
            return false;
        });

   });
```

**In Functions.php**

```
function ajax_action_stuff() {
if(isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {

    function set_html_content_type()
    {
    return 'text/html';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['mail']) && isset($_POST['query'])) {  

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $to = 'vigneshmoha@gmail.com';

    if($name == "" || $email == "" || $query == "") {
        echo "Fail";
        return false;
    }

    $subject = "Website - Query from ".$name;
    $message = "Hi,
        <p><strong>Name</strong>:".$name."</p>
        <p><strong>Mail</strong>:".$email."</p>
        <h3><strong>Query</h3>
        <p>".$query."</p>";
    $headers[] = 'From: no-reply@gmail.com'."\r\n";
    $headers[] = '';

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
    $mailsent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); // reset content-type to to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578


    if($mailsent) {
        echo $to;
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
   } else {
    echo 'error';   
   }

 } else {
    echo 'error';
 }
 die();
   }
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' );
```

Comment: There is a possibility that your email is being marked as spam, or it's simply your email provider is not allowing it to reach your inbox, are you sending via SMTP? Do you have SPF records setup? If you are sending an email from your website, and have the from header set as `@gmail.com` or `@hotmail.com`, this will surely not arrive in your inbox as the email is not originating from the gmail or hotmail servers, it's coming from yours, so it think's you are trying a phishing attack

Comment: No, Its not marked as spam. I have checked the spam too. Mail is not receiving at all. wp_mail() should returns true once it has sent the mail right? So Should i change the from header to something else?

Comment: Yes that's correct, but that means the mail has left **your** server, it doesn't mean it'll arrive in your inbox, as there are many other steps between your server and your inbox, and a few different things could of went wrong in this process. Try testing the from header, change to `example@yourdomainname.com`

Comment: Great! Its working. I have changed the from header to example@mydomainname.com. Thanks.

Comment: Let me add it as an answer for the sake of stack overflow's rules

Comment: Sure. Please do that. It'll help someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a possibility that your email is being marked as spam, or it's simply your email provider is not allowing it to reach your inbox, are you sending via SMTP?

Do you have SPF records setup? If you are sending an email from your website, and have the from header set as `@gmail.com` or `@hotmail.com`, this will surely not arrive in your inbox as the email is not originating from the gmail or hotmail servers, it's coming from yours, so it think's you are trying some phishing attack.

Edit:

> No, Its not marked as spam. I have checked the spam too. Mail is not
>   receiving at all. wp_mail() should returns true once it has sent the
>   mail right? So Should i change the from header to something else?
>
> -vigneshmoha

That means the mail has left your server, it doesn't mean it'll arrive in your inbox, as there are many other steps between your server and your inbox, and a few different things could of went wrong in this process. Try testing out the `From:` header, change to `example@yourdomainname.com`

Comment: Another consideration is that the email is not being sent at all. Most hosts, especially shared hosting, have specific requirements that disallow sending script-based emails with an email address that does not match the domain of the site. In this case, wp_mail will return true because it generates the email, but it will never go anywhere.  Keep in mind that some hosts will not only require the domain to match, but also will require that the actual address be an actual email. Check with your host about their specific requirements.