# WP Mail SMTP returns true in test email, but not receiving the email

Tags: wordpress, email

I am using SMTP plugin in wordpress and I created a valid email on my server to use for SMTP, the authentication is also successful, things are good at this point. Now, when I send the test email the response is true but I am not actually receiving the email on my test email provided in the field.

[wp_mail returns true but not receiving mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584505/wp-mail-returns-true-but-not-receiving-mails)

This question is same but this does not solve my problem because I am using info@myserver.com as FROM email. I am not using any external email server. Its from my own server.

Please help, this is really important.

EDIT :

Gmail is rejecting the emails, here is the response,

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; server.servername.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;mygmailemail@gmail.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [192.3.7.194      12] Our system has    detected that this message is
550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. f20si332031igo.32 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Email return true if the function is successfull but don't return informations if the mail was send.

What server is it ?
Is there a smtp on it?

Comment: For what it's worth: PHP's mail returns true when the mail has been processed and sent to the server's mail handler. wp_mail=true, means you're good on the PHP end, so your problem is either in the mail server or between mail server and mail receiver. **1.** Check your mail server logs. They will tell you the status of your mail, and if something went wrong there. If all is well there, **2.** Check from the receiving end. There are tons of things going on there, like Reverse DNS lookups and who knows what else :(

Comment: If you have sudo on the server, [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) may save your life here.

Comment: @kevinard I have edited my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

you don't care much if Gmail reject this test e-mail, the e-mails are send, check this [article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/) to reduce the spam detection and check the suggested [Gmail actions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

Comment: I tried real emails too, with unique content, not just test emails, the problem is same for all emails. I got to know the gmail rejects the emails with wrong header info. So I posted the response to let you guys check if my headers are wrong. According to me its correct. Please check and see if you can help me. The content is not like spam also.

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with the header, maybe gmail is temporary blocking your server because of the many requests

Comment: Its not just gmail, yahoo responds that my server IP is in their spam list.. what can I do about that ?

Comment: every provider like yahoo here: https://www.rackaid.com/blog/how-to-remove-your-email-server-from-yahoos-blacklist/ will have a procedure to unban your ip